# Trigger Bamboo build plan only for master branch

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

I have a Bamboo plan to build and then deploy my application. There's another build plan which should be triggered after the deployment of the first one. This is done with the `after-deployment` trigger:

```yml
triggers:
  - after-deployment:
      deployment-project: My Application
      environment: Dev
  - after-deployment:
      deployment-project: My Application
      environment: QA
```

However, as long as the deployment happens from the master only, I would like to trigger the secondary build plan for the master branch only, too. However, it is triggered for the feature branches as well.

I have tried cleaning up the main `triggers` block and moving the trigger into the `branch-overrides`, like this, but that didn't help:

```yml
triggers: []

branch-overrides:
  - master:
      triggers:
        - after-deployment:
            deployment-project: My Application
            environment: Dev
        - after-deployment:
            deployment-project: My Application
            environment: QA
```

What's the right way to let the secondary build plan be triggered for the master branch only?

Answer (score 0):

keep your common triggers in yaml, create a manual branch through the UI, call it something like "master deploy" and apply the custom after deployment trigger on it.